# В каком типе нужно хранить запись о балансе?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. В каком типе нужно хранить запись о балансе? Учитывая что баланс может быть не целым числом (900.000002), и учитывая что на сайте им можно манипулировать (пополнять, тратить).

интересно, а что если в VARCHAR ? - почему нет?

Comment: decimal / numeric

Comment: @Mike интересно, а что если в VARCHAR ?

Comment: а зачем ? вы тогда его даже сортировать не сможете. или вас устроит, что 2 будет считаться больше, чем 1999999. тем более что decimal специально предназначен именно для такого применения, а внутренне представляет из себя тот же varchar только с пониманием БД, что это число

Comment: @Mike то есть проблемы будет только в сортировке?

Comment: с любыми сравнениями. даже нормально проверить что значение стало меньше нуля не сможете

Comment: Зачем varchar, когда есть decimal

Comment: @Mike лучше бы сразу ответ написали, вопрос в открытых не висел бы.

Comment: @Mike, >>а внутренне представляет из себя тот же varchar только с пониманием БД << — всё же он сильно [отличается](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) от varchar'а.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `Decimal` или `Numeric` - они предназначен именно для хранения точных числовых данных, например денег. Выдержка из [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html):

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.

По поводу:

> интересно, а что если в VARCHAR ? - почему нет?

Как писали в комментариях, вы не сможете выполнять математические операции, сортировку средствами БД "из коробки" - вам придется каждый раз выполнять преобразования в числовой тип, проводить операции и записывать обратно в строковый.

Связанный вопрос с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628637/best-data-type-for-storing-currency-values-in-a-mysql-database)